# Как работает данный цикл внутри потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть код из книги Эффективное программирование :

```
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested){
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        });
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

Данный код приводит к бесконечному циклу внутри потока t.
Но если в данный цикл , добавить System.out.printl();

```
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (!StopThread.stopRequested){
                i++;
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        });
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

То в таком случае цикл прерывается.
Как это работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В изначальном коде `stopRequested` не `volatile`, нет блока `synchronized` (или других методов обеспечения видимости изменений между потоками). Поэтому, ожидаемо, такой цикл не завершается.

При добавлении `System.out.println()` ситуация меняется. Внутри `System.out.println` есть точка синхронизации (т.е. или чтение из `volatile` переменной или `synchronized` блок), и потому изменения сделанные в `stopRequested` в другом потоке становятся видимыми этому потоку.

Немного добавлю о том, почему оригинальный цикл не завершается. Операции обращения к памяти [очень дорогие](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), можно считать, что в 100 раз медленнее чем работа с L1 кешем. Если каждое обращение к переменной будет читать или писать в память, то это существенно замедлит работу программы **без надобности** в подавляющем большинстве случаев.

Поэтому, спецификация java разрешает реализации опускать какие-то операции доступа к памяти и пользоваться локальным (для потока) кешем. Java memory model это раздел спецификации описывающий формальные правила, какие операции обязаны читать и писать в память (я тут пишу упрощенно, для лучшего понимания). Программист же знает, когда переменная может быть использована несколькими потоками и должен явно воспользоваться механизмами, которые будут гарантировать, что изменения будут видны в других потоках.

В частности, обычную (не `volatile`) перемененную вне блоков синхронизации среда не обязана синхронизировать. И любая достаточно оптимальная реализация так будет делать. Поэтому, то что изменения сделанные в одном потоке, не видны в другом - это ожидаемо с точки зрения спецификации, но, согласен, далеко неочевидно новичкам в multithreading.

> разве в какой-то момент Тред t не должен актуализировать данные в своем кэше из мейн мемори

Нет. Ничто в спецификации java не требует, чтоб это произошло. `t` может вечно видеть начальное значение переменной и это не будет нарушать спецификацию.

> Насчет println в цикле - я же не говорю ему какую переменную стоит выводить. Пустой println ставит /n . Этого все равно достаточно для видимости изменений из другого потока?

Я не знаю точно, как устроен `println`, но достаточно чтоб в нем был выполнен `synchronized` блок или функция или чтение из `volatile` переменной, и это приведет к тому, что все изменения сделанные в основной памяти станут видны нашему потоку.

Comment: А почему он ОЖИДАЕМО не завершается? Ведь мейн тред обновляет переменную stopRequested. И разве в какой-то момент Тред t не должен актуализировать данные в своем кэше из мейн мемори? 

Насчет println в цикле - я же не говорю ему какую переменную стоит выводить. Пустой println ставит /n . Этого все равно достаточно для видимости изменений из другого потока?

Comment: Добавил объяснение.

Comment: Я посмотрел как реализован println и оказалось что в нем синхронизированный блок кода. 
После этого я подумал - почему-бы мне не сделать пустой класс с одним синхронизированным методом без логики, и подсунуть его вместо println в цикл. 
Это сработало! изменения стали видны. Очень интересно как так получается. 
Благодарю за ответ !

Comment: Лучше сделайте переменную `volatile` это гораздо лучше