# Приложение на Spring является многопоточным или нет?

Tags: java, spring

Мне необходимо создать несколько сервисов в которых будут крутится бесконечные циклы, с возможностью их остановки.
Вроде как напрашивается реализовать все в отдельных потоках.
Я попробовал создать их в приложении на Spring, написав небольшое тестовое приложение.
Использование Spring в данном приложении обусловлено тем, что придется подключать к нему web-интерфейс. Используется встроенный веб-сервер Apache Tomcat.

```
@Service
public class FirstService
 public isStart = false;
 private action() {
    while (isStart) {
        ... 
    } 
 }
}
@Service
public class NextService
 public isStart = false;
 private action() {
    while (isStart) {
        ... 
    } 
 }
}
```

Запуск и остановку сервиса осуществляю через контроллеры

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  FirstService firstService;
  
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> post(@PathVariable(PARAM_ACTION) Integer action) {
    firstService.isStart = ...;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Вроде как все работает, т.е. получается, что приложение многопоточное? Иначе бы все останавливалось, пока не будет выполнен первый же метод action
Вопрос:
стоит ли мне создавать многопоточное приложение, если все и так работает? Или это не очень хорошее решение и все-таки надо реализовывать используя стандартное решение с потоками?
Или может у Spring есть другое готовое решение и для таких случаев?

Хотелось бы использовать для решения этой задачи что-то готовое от Spring. Но я не знаю какой из его компонентов может мне в этом помочь. Основное требование это быстродействие, время цикла не должно превышать 20мсек, т.е. это должны быть не очень тяжелые компоненты. В каждой итерации цикла выполняется прием от 300 до 800 байт данных по изернету, обработка их и отправка по другому адресу. И таких сервисов может быть от трех до пяти одновременно. Если у Spring есть компоненты, которые справятся с такой задачей, то буду рад если подскажите их названия, а я уже займусь их изучением.
Другими словами мне нужен совет в каком направлении копать, юзать какой-то компонент от Spring или начинать изучать многопоточные приложения и создавать свой компонент.

По сети (ETH) происходит прием массива байтов (300-800 байт), они могут приходить с двух или трех каналов, обработка заключается в переводе этих байтов в физические величины для вывода на фронт (REST API) и формирования новых массивов байт из полученного набора для передачи уже по одну - двум каналам.
Циклы приема-передачи должны иметь возможность запускаться по сигналу с фронта и так же останавливаться, с возможностью остановки каждого в отдельности. Частота приема-передачи по каждому каналу 20-100мс

Comment: Такие сервисы надо создавать в отдельном потоке, сразу же при загрузке приложения. Иначе это может привести к ошибке 503.

Comment: В вашем примере не ясно, где и когда вызываются методы типа `firstService.action`. Если из контроллера, то это плохо, так как вы занимаете потоки из пула обработки http запросов. Правильно их вызывать в фоне используя [TaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-task-executor-usage) явно или используя [@Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async). И еще у вас проблема с корректной остановкой см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1302473/218971

Comment: Что и как Вы будете принимать по сети и как обрабатывать?

Comment: добавил описание в теле вопроса

Answer (score 2):

> **Дисклеймер:**
> Данный ответ написан по первой версии данного вопроса, в которой  было непонятно, что происходит внутри данных сервисов и нужно было ответить является ли Spring многопоточным приложением или нет.
> Поэтоуму я не вдавался в подробности работы с многопоточностью в контексте конкретных задач и сфокусировался на основном вопросе.
> Я надеюсь, что от @Alex поступит обратная связь и он чуть подробнее объяснит, что именно он хочет сделать, чтобы можно было предложить более конкретные рекомендации и инструменты.

Как видно из примеров, Вы разрабатываете веб-приложение.

### Веб-приложения и обработка http-запросов

Если Вы используете **Spring Boot**, то скорее всего для обработки HTTP-запросов используется встроенный веб-сервер **Apache Tomcat**.
Данный веб-сервер обрабатывает запросы в многопоточном режиме и никаких дополнительных усилий для этого предпринимать не нужно.

При желании вы можете настроить максимально возможное количество потоков

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=100
```

или установить минимальное количество потоков в режиме ожидания

```
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=50
```

Если Вы используете не встроенный `Apache Tomcat`, то все вышеописанное относится и к другим веб-серверам (Jetty, JBoss, etc.)

### Другие компоненты

Spring состоит из большого количества компонентов.
И многие из них, из коробки работают в многопоточном режиме.
Многие также поддерживают настройку, как в примере с Apache Tomcat:

- Будь то пул подключений к базе данных
- или количество обработчиков очереди сообщений RabbitMQ.

Тем не менее это не значит, что все компоненты поголовно работают в многопоточном режиме.
Как и то, что если конкретный компонент имеет такую возможность,то это не значит, что он по умолчанию будет настроен нужным Вам образом.

### Собственные компоненты и сервисы

Также стоит отметить, что обеспечить корректную работу в многопоточном режиме для собственных компонентов - это ваша собственная задача, за Вас ее никто не решит.
Однако, прежде чем заниматься этим убедитесь, что Вы правильно понимаете данную тему.
Также перед тем как писать какой-то свой компонент убедитесь, что в Spring'e нет инструментов, которые бы позволили бы вам решить вашу задачу с минимальным количеством усилий и без особых глубоких познаний в многопоточности.
Для большинства задач такие инструменты есть.

### Ваш кейс

По умолчанию Spring создает Ваши бины как синглтоны.
Это значит, что при обращении из любого контроллера, при обработке любого запроса(которые, как мы выяснили выше, работают в многопоточном режиме) обращаются к одному и тому же экземпляру Вашего сервиса и к одной и той же переменной `isStart`.

В Вашем случае, возможно, этого достаточно, однако, в более сложных случаях вам было бы необходимо поработать над потокобезопасным использованием ресурсов внутри вашего компонента, т.к. к одному и тому же экземпляру вашего компонента могут одновременно пытаться обращаться из разных потоков.
Рекомендации для написания потокобезопасного сервиса, ровно те же самые, что и для написания любого другого потокобезопасного кода в Java.
Данная тема достаточно обширна и выходит далеко за рамки обсуждения данного вопроса, чтобы пытаться описать их здесь.

Comment: `isStart` нужно сделать volatile чтоб правильно работало